# Sign app with the App Sign key from Play Console android

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

Let's say that i have developed an application, signed it and released it in Play Store and some users have already downloaded it.

I have registered the sign key to the App Signing section of the Play Console, so it says that Google protects my key if i loose it or it has been compromised.

Well, let us say that i have lost it. What exactly should i do to deploy an update to my application?

Answer (score -1):

You can't update the application now because you've lost the key. So you can't update the application with same name.

**Solutions:**

- Kindly use any back up software to back up your key
- Change package name and upload it from start